# Why UITapGestureRecognizer is not Work For UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have added Simple `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `UIImageView` and created ***Gesture Method*** that gets called when user ***taps/touches*** `UIImageView`

**My Code IS :**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *eagleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(eagleTapGestureIsCall:)];
eagleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.egaleImgView addGestureRecognizer:eagleTapGesture];
```

**Gesture Method:**

```
- (void)eagleTapGestureIsCall:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];
    NSLog(@"Eagle is Tapped X - %f",location.x);
    NSLog(@"Eagle is Tapped Y - %f",location.y);
}
```

Here If I add Gesture on `UIView` instead of `self.egaleImgView` then it works *(I mean Gesture Method is called)* but why it is not working on `self.egaleImgView` ???

After Googling I found that, might be `UIView` intercepts the touches before they can reach `UIImageView`.

So I added the following line at start of `viewDidLoad`

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO; /// Here i set userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Following describes structure for better understanding.

```
                main UIView
                  |     |

(Sub view) mainBackGroungImageView //// size is similar to size of main UIView
                  |     |
        (Sub view) gestureAdded ImageView
```

**EDITED:**

Sorry guys for forgetting to mention that I already added `self.egaleImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` to my imageView, but it is not working for me.

Please give me suggestions on my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you enable user interaction? On the image view itself.

Comment: By default user action is disabled for imageviews

Comment: Do not disable `userInteraction` on the view.

Comment: Can you check if the superView of imageView is not clipping the imageView.

Answer (score 12):

Set your `ImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` because it is **NO** by default. And it would be better to set the view's user interaction to YES too.

Comment: sorry for i forget to mention that i already done it (i putted self.egaleImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; in my code); but its not useful for me :(

Comment: I have the same problem , but this answer fixed my problem!

Answer (score 2):

if you set the `userInteractionEnable = NO` on parent view it will cascaded to all the child views.Keep it enabled.Instead of tap gesture you ca try something like this:

In order to get the click on the image view you can use the `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` method.

In  `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` of your view you can get the view that is being touched.It can go something like this,

```
CGPoint locPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
UIView* touchedSubView = [self.view hitTest:locPoint withEvent:event];
```

Then you can add a check for the view class and implement what is required,like so

```
if ([touchedSubView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

use [recognizer locationInView:self];

Comment: What is this this is not my issue, please first read my question its only information for me it is not important for me :(

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView userInteractionEnabled is disabled. Make it unable.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *eagleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(eagleTapGestureIsCall:)];
eagleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.egaleImgView addGestureRecognizer:eagleTapGesture]; 
self.egaleImgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

I had same problem. This solved it.

Comment: Then some other view is above that. Have you added any other view?

Comment: I also try to  do [self.mainBG bringSubviewToFront:self.view];
    [self.egaleImgView bringSubviewToFront:self.mainBG]; but its not work for me :(

Comment: while inserting egaleImgView use insertsubviewAtIndex:99.

Comment: thanks for replay but i can not understand what you are saying >? please add it as answer with some description , thanks :)